# Absolute positioned div with overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have a div that I place on my page which has `style = "z-index:1;position:absolute;"` This div's (x,y) position is set using

```
$(onMouse).css('left',(mouseX - offSetX) + "px");
$(onMouse).css('top',(fixY) +"px");
```

dynamically and that piece works fine. (But I thought it might be relevant)

In that div I place a table that consists of two rows. The first row is a table with one cell.  The second row consists of a new div whose style I set with

```
$(scrollDiv).css("overflow","hidden");
$(scrollDiv).css("position","relative");
$(scrollDiv).css("height","100px");
```

This second div contains a table, which has tons of rows in it.  I would like it to cut off those rows at the scrollDiv's height, but it doesn't do this.  It just shows all the rows that exist instead.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit #1**

Thank you *Tim Dodd* and *Dan* for your responses!  I've taken the JSFiddle you created and modified it to be a generic version of what I meant in order to be more clear.  You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/S3sh7/1/

What I want is for the table that gets created on click to be showing the same rows as the original table.  I would think you could do this by setting the `overflow` and `height` properties as I did with the `.pieceOfTable` CSS class but it isn't working.  Do you know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle demo we can look at?

Comment: Just updated with one.  Was leaving work when I wrote this out so I didn't get a chance to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first thing...

```
$(onMouse).css({
  left: (mouseX - offSetX) + "px",
  top: fixY +"px"
});

$(scrollDiv).css({
  overflow: 'hidden',
  position: 'relative',
  height: '100px'
});
```

Aside from that, the div showing up on click has no height value or `overflow:hidden`. Might also make sense to give it a border so users can see where/why its cut off... ?

```
#floater {  <-- based off of your fiddle. Update if needed.
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't quite understand the logic of why setting overflow-x to auto fixes it though.  It seems it would all have to do with overflow-y... Can you explain that a bit more?  If not thanks anyway, I appreciate it!

Comment: One more thing to add, yeah I hadn't given a height to the div overall but i had given a height to the div that was inside of the table that was inside of that div so i figured that would be good enough...  I see now that wasn't the case.

Comment: Yes... that should have been overflow-y. Oversight on my part.

Comment: Ok, great. I just thought i may have been missing something.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this a million times which is the only reason I understood your question. You need to do something like this.

```
<div id="TblWrapper">
 <div id= "TblHeader"><table><th>ColumnHeader</th></table></div>
<div id = "TblBody">
   <table>
   <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <!-- more Rows-->
   </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Then in the style you make do something like this...

```
#TblWrapper
{
    Height:210 px;
}

#TblBody
{
    Height: 200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mL47j/5/) for an example. I've added some background colors to the example so you can see how the whole thing is built.

The beautiful part is its all capable without any clunky JavaScript. Which in this case would have caused scrolling to appear choppy.

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow-y:scroll; on #TblBody or table and set it to the desired height.

Answer (score 0):

Something like defining a few --

```
min-width: define; 
width: define;
max-width: define;
```

and toggling `overflow-y:` with a little bit of nesting action?